# How to get a sibling element by class name upon button click?

Tags: javascript

I have a table with similar rows and I am trying to get the value "Star" when the button is clicked.

```
<tr>
    <td class="shape">Star</td>
    <td class="weight">3</td>
    <td><button>Click</button></td>
</tr>
```

Code I have tried:

```
<script>
    const delButton = event.target;
    var prevShape = delButton.getElementsByClass("shape").previousSibling.innerHtml;  
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegate:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // on page load
  document.getElementById("tb").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.tagName === "BUTTON") {
      const shape = tgt.closest("tr").querySelector(".shape").textContent;
      console.log(shape);
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="tb">
    <tr>
      <td class="shape">Circle</td>
      <td class="weight">3</td>
      <td><button>Click</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="shape">Star</td>
      <td class="weight">3</td>
      <td><button>Click</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```